# Is it safe to hold reference to a variable declared in a statement-block in C++?

Tags: c++

Something like this:

```
void f()
{
    int* p = NULL;

    if (condition)
    {
        int a = 3;
        p = &a;
    }

    // use p...
}
```

And if no, in what circumstances would this go wrong?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, plain and simple.  The compiler is even free to turn your program to junk if you use `p` afterwords.

Comment: It's undefined behavior even if it works with some compilers in some cases.  A compiler is free to re-use that part of the stack as soon as the block ends and fill it with anything at all.

Comment: It looks like this question might have meant to be marked as C since it looks like C code. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe?

No, it is not safe as it is considered undefined behavior by the standard. Accessing the memory of something after its scope has expired means that it can equal anything.

> In what circumstances would this go wrong?

Let's take a look at your current example:

```
void f()
{
    int* p = NULL;

    if (condition)
    {
        int a = 3;
        p = &a;
    }
    int x = 5;
    // p may now point to x,
    // or some other variable on the stack,
    // or it might not do either and may point to invalid memory.
    // it depends on what your compiler decides to do.
    // this is what is meant by "undefined behavior."
}
```

On an unrelated note, if p was never assigned, p still points to `NULL` and accessing it will throw an exception.

So, what's the alternative? You've got more than one option, but here is the simplest in my opinion that still maintains the same usage:

```
void f()
{
    int* p = NULL;

    if (condition)
    {
        p = new int{3};
        int& a = *p;
        // use a
    }

    // use p as you normally would, be sure to check for nullptr
    // you must delete p as well.
}
```

Comment: _if p was never assigned, p still points to `NULL` and accessing it will throw an exception_ No it won't.  Dereferencing a null pointer results in undefined behavior the same as dereferencing any invalid pointer.